# Rpy2: TypeError: Parameter 'categories' must be list-like

Tags: r, python-3.x, dataframe, rpy2

I want to convert the r Dataframe to pandas dataframe consider the following code as an illustration

```
import rpy2, rpy2.robjects as robjects, rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector
import os
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
base = importr('base')
print(base.R_home())

# install packages in r from python

packageNames  = ('ggplot2', 'hexbin', 'MVN','afex', 'emmeans')
utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)

packnames_to_install = [x for x in packageNames if not rpackages.isinstalled(x)]

if len(packnames_to_install) > 0:
    utils.install_packages(StrVector(packnames_to_install))


# Read table function in r to python dataframe
data = robjects.r('read.table(file =' \
       '"http://personality-project.org/r/datasets/R.appendix3.data", header = T)')

data.head()
```

[image]

I want to transform this dataframe to python dataframe

as follow

```
# Convert R Dataframe to python Dataframe
# !pip install tzlocal
# type(data)
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pd_df = pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe(data)
pd_df
```

I receive the following error

```
TypeError: Parameter 'categories' must be list-like, was <rpy2.rinterface.StrSexpVector - Python:0x0000021E88AB4FC0 / R:0x0000021EF1A6AE98>
```

How to get it working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
import rpy2, rpy2.robjects as robjects, rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector
#Converting data frames back and forth between rpy2 and pandas
from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
import os
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
base = importr('base')
data = robjects.r('read.table(file =' \
       '"http://personality-project.org/r/datasets/R.appendix3.data", header = T)')
data.head()
```

from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri

pandas2ri.activate()
Converting data frames back and forth between rpy2 and pandas

[image]